# Vuejs, how to put data in children component?

Tags: vue.js

I want to set `currentView` variable if `changePassword` method start.
I tried `$broadcast`, if the event is in Model var it works, but if I put the event in Setting var, `$broadcast` does not work. and I tried `$children` too, but didn't work.

```js
var Settings = Vue.extend({
  template: '#temp-setting',
  data: function() {
    return { currentView: '' };
  },
  components: {
    'change-password': ChangePassword
  }
});
```

This is full vuejs code

```js
var ChangePassword = Vue.extend({
 template: '#temp-change-password'
});

var Settings = Vue.extend({
 template: '#temp-setting',
 data: function() {
  return { currentView: '' };
 },
 components: {
  'change-password': ChangePassword
 }
});

var Modal = Vue.extend({
 template: '#temp-modal',
 methods: {
  close: function() {
   Router.go('/');

   $('#modal').modal('hide');
  }
 }
});

var MainApp = Vue.extend({
 methods: {
  changePassword: function() {
   Router.go('/settings/change-password');

   $('#modal').modal({
    backdrop: false,
    keyboard: false
   });
  }
 },
 ready: function() {
  Router.go('/');
 }
});

var Router = new VueRouter();

Router.map({
 '/': {
  component: Modal,
 },
 '/settings': {
  component: Modal,
  subRoutes: {
   '/change-password': {
    component: Settings
   }
  }
 }
});

Router.start(MainApp, 'body');
```